# Kernel CRASH of NIntegrate with a complicated compiled integrand

Tags: numerical-integration, crash

When I `NIntegrate` the integrand with the particular parameter showing below the Kernel **crash** without any message.

But if I change the "range" parameter a little bit, the Kernel won't crash. The crash problem seems to occur only under certain parameters.

Because I want to make a density plot of the integral as a function of the parameters, this crash problem under certain parameters always breaks the density plot process.

This crash problem happens on both Mac and Win10:

- MacOS Big Sur 11.2.2, Mathematica 12.1.1.0
- Win10, Mathematica 12.1.1.0

```
(*Integrand*)

expression1 = {{-0.03783737745791316` + 
     52.07594879537986` (k1^2 + k2^2) - 
     0.0006566020385220937` \[GothicCapitalB]3, \
-0.00020215783672119025` (\[GothicCapitalB]1 - 
       I \[GothicCapitalB]2), (0.` + 0.` I) + 
     1/2 (273.35324964239567` (k1 - I k2)^3 - 
        22.668570452264646` (k1 + I k2)^3), 
    0.` + I (k1 - I k2) (-1.0301133331497063` - 
        370.16816003256605` (k1^2 + 
           k2^2))}, {-0.00020215783672119025` (\[GothicCapitalB]1 + 
       I \[GothicCapitalB]2), -0.03783737745791316` + 
     52.07594879537986` (k1^2 + k2^2) + 
     0.0006566020385220937` \[GothicCapitalB]3, 
    0.` - I (k1 + I k2) (-1.0301133331497063` - 
        370.16816003256605` (k1^2 + k2^2)), (0.` + 0.` I) + 
     1/2 (22.668570452264646` (k1 - I k2)^3 - 
        273.35324964239567` (k1 + I k2)^3)}, {(0.` + 0.` I) + 
     1/2 (-22.668570452264646` (k1 - I k2)^3 + 
        273.35324964239567` (k1 + I k2)^3), 
    0.` + I (k1 - I k2) (-1.0301133331497063` - 
        370.16816003256605` (k1^2 + k2^2)), -0.03304414880767263` + 
     95.54303239292248` (k1^2 + k2^2) - 
     0.0015031216532114644` \[GothicCapitalB]3, \
-0.00017807130082869512` (\[GothicCapitalB]1 - 
       I \[GothicCapitalB]2)}, {0.` - 
     I (k1 + I k2) (-1.0301133331497063` - 
        370.16816003256605` (k1^2 + k2^2)), (0.` + 0.` I) + 
     1/2 (-273.35324964239567` (k1 - I k2)^3 + 
        22.668570452264646` (k1 + 
           I k2)^3), -0.00017807130082869512` (\[GothicCapitalB]1 + 
       I \[GothicCapitalB]2), -0.03304414880767263` + 
     95.54303239292248` (k1^2 + k2^2) + 
     0.0015031216532114644` \[GothicCapitalB]3}};
expression2 = {{104.15189759075972` k1s, 0, 
    1/2 (820.059748927187` (k1s - I k2)^2 - 
       68.00571135679394` (k1s + I k2)^2), (0.` - 
        740.3363200651321` I) k1s (k1s - I k2) + 
     I (-1.0301133331497063` - 
        370.16816003256605` (k1s^2 + k2^2))}, {0, 
    104.15189759075972` k1s, (0.` + 740.3363200651321` I) k1s (k1s + 
        I k2) - I (-1.0301133331497063` - 
        370.16816003256605` (k1s^2 + k2^2)), 
    1/2 (68.00571135679394` (k1s - I k2)^2 - 
       820.059748927187` (k1s + I k2)^2)}, {1/
     2 (-68.00571135679394` (k1s - I k2)^2 + 
       820.059748927187` (k1s + I k2)^2), (0.` - 
        740.3363200651321` I) k1s (k1s - I k2) + 
     I (-1.0301133331497063` - 370.16816003256605` (k1s^2 + k2^2)), 
    191.08606478584497` k1s, 
    0}, {(0.` + 740.3363200651321` I) k1s (k1s + I k2) - 
     I (-1.0301133331497063` - 370.16816003256605` (k1s^2 + k2^2)), 
    1/2 (-820.059748927187` (k1s - I k2)^2 + 
       68.00571135679394` (k1s + I k2)^2), 0, 
    191.08606478584497` k1s}};
expression3 = {{104.15189759075972` k2s, 0, 
    1/2 ((0.` - 820.059748927187` I) (k1 - I k2s)^2 - (0.` + 
          68.00571135679394` I) (k1 + 
          I k2s)^2), -1.0301133331497063` - (0.` + 
        740.3363200651321` I) (k1 - I k2s) k2s - 
     370.16816003256605` (k1^2 + k2s^2)}, {0, 
    104.15189759075972` k2s, -1.0301133331497063` + (0.` + 
        740.3363200651321` I) (k1 + I k2s) k2s - 
     370.16816003256605` (k1^2 + k2s^2), 
    1/2 ((0.` - 68.00571135679394` I) (k1 - I k2s)^2 - (0.` + 
          820.059748927187` I) (k1 + I k2s)^2)}, {1/
     2 ((0.` + 68.00571135679394` I) (k1 - I k2s)^2 + (0.` + 
          820.059748927187` I) (k1 + 
          I k2s)^2), -1.0301133331497063` - (0.` + 
        740.3363200651321` I) (k1 - I k2s) k2s - 
     370.16816003256605` (k1^2 + k2s^2), 191.08606478584497` k2s, 
    0}, {-1.0301133331497063` + (0.` + 740.3363200651321` I) (k1 + 
        I k2s) k2s - 370.16816003256605` (k1^2 + k2s^2), 
    1/2 ((0.` + 820.059748927187` I) (k1 - I k2s)^2 + (0.` + 
          68.00571135679394` I) (k1 + I k2s)^2), 0, 
    191.08606478584497` k2s}};
HamiltCompiled = 
  Compile[{{k1, _Real}, {k2, _Real}, {\[GothicCapitalB]1, _Real}, {\
\[GothicCapitalB]2, _Real}, {\[GothicCapitalB]3, _Real}}, 
   Evaluate[expression1], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}];
Dk1HamiltCompiled = 
  Compile[{{k1s, _Real}, {k2, _Real}, {\[GothicCapitalB]1, _Real}, {\
\[GothicCapitalB]2, _Real}, {\[GothicCapitalB]3, _Real}}, 
   Evaluate[expression2], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}];
Dk2HamiltCompiled = 
  Compile[{{k1, _Real}, {k2s, _Real}, {\[GothicCapitalB]1, _Real}, {\
\[GothicCapitalB]2, _Real}, {\[GothicCapitalB]3, _Real}}, 
   Evaluate[expression3], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}];
OccupiedCurvatureCompiled[\[Mu]_?NumericQ, k1_?NumericQ, 
   k2_?NumericQ, \[GothicCapitalB]1_, \[GothicCapitalB]2_, \
\[GothicCapitalB]3_] := 
  Block[{Mx1, Mx2, values, vectors, curvaturesList},
   {values, vectors} = 
    Eigensystem@
     HamiltCompiled[k1, 
      k2, \[GothicCapitalB]1, \[GothicCapitalB]2, \
\[GothicCapitalB]3];
   {values, vectors} = {values[[#]], vectors[[#]]} &[
     Ordering@values];
   Mx1 = vectors\[Conjugate].(Dk1HamiltCompiled[k1, 
       k2, \[GothicCapitalB]1, \[GothicCapitalB]2, \
\[GothicCapitalB]3]).vectors\[Transpose];
   Mx2 = vectors\[Conjugate].(Dk2HamiltCompiled[k1, 
       k2, \[GothicCapitalB]1, \[GothicCapitalB]2, \
\[GothicCapitalB]3]).vectors\[Transpose];
   curvaturesList = 
    Re[I Total[(# - #\[Transpose])]] &[
     Mx1*Mx2\[Transpose]*
      Table[If[n1 == n2, 0, 1/(values[[n1]] - values[[n2]])^2], {n1, 
        1, 4}, {n2, 1, 4}]];
   curvaturesList.Boole@Thread[values < \[Mu]]
   ];
```

```
(*No Crash*)
With[{range = 
   0.0006` + 
    0.00025*19.`, \[Mu] = -0.034637500000000015`, \[GothicCapitalB]1 =
    0., \[GothicCapitalB]2 = 19.`, \[GothicCapitalB]3 = 0.}, 
 NIntegrate[
  OccupiedCurvatureCompiled[\[Mu], k1, 
   k2, \[GothicCapitalB]1, \[GothicCapitalB]2, \[GothicCapitalB]3], \
{k1, -range, range}, {k2, -range, range}, MinRecursion -> 2, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3]]
```

```
(*Crash*)
With[{range = 
   0.0005` + 
    0.00025*19.`, \[Mu] = -0.034637500000000015`, \[GothicCapitalB]1 =
    0., \[GothicCapitalB]2 = 19.`, \[GothicCapitalB]3 = 0.}, 
 NIntegrate[
  OccupiedCurvatureCompiled[\[Mu], k1, 
   k2, \[GothicCapitalB]1, \[GothicCapitalB]2, \[GothicCapitalB]3], \
{k1, -range, range}, {k2, -range, range}, MinRecursion -> 2, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3]]
```

Comment: I verified the posted code crashes my version of Mathematica, 12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit). I suggest your report this to WRI.

Comment: @AntonAntonov MacOS Big Sur 11.2.2, Mathematica 12.1.1.0; Win10, Mathematica 12.1.1.0

Comment: @AntonAntonov Could you tell me how to report this to WRI? Thanks

Comment: "Could you tell me how to report this to WRI? " --  Please see https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback . Also, this MSE discussion: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-to-report-bugs .